# More general Axiom of Infinity

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I was reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity, in relation to Zermelo Set theory and was wondering why the axiom is posed as
$$
\exists Z(\varnothing \in Z \wedge \forall x(x\in Z \to x\cup \{x\}\in Z))
$$
or an alternative mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory#The_axioms_of_Zermelo_set_theory)
$$
\exists Z(\varnothing \in Z \wedge \forall x(x\in Z \to \{x\}\in Z)).
$$
My question is that, is there a reason for these presentations that specify exactly what kinds of sets are in the infinite set $Z$? Would it be insufficient to instead take
$$
\exists Z(\varnothing \in Z \wedge \forall x(x\in Z\to \exists y(y\in Z \wedge x\in y)))
$$
to be the axiom?

Comment: There is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity#An_apparently_weaker_version) version on wikipedia. However, these versions depend a lot on the other axioms to be useful, while the more specific versions do not.

Comment: The Infinity Axiom, intuitively, is the statement " There exists an Inductive Set" . An interesting fact about Inductive Sets, is that all of them contain the natural numbers ( as constructed in ZFC). So, yes, we know, to some extent what is inside the Inductive Set Z. Being able to construct the set of natural numbers, and utilize mathematical Induction, is one of the very useful aspects of even having the Infinity Axiom in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you suggest will work in the standard framework of $\sf ZF$, or at least in the presence of Regularity, as we can prove that $\in$ does not contain any cycles, so the set you describe will necessarily be infinite.

In fact, we don't even care if $\varnothing$ is a member or not at this point. All we need is that $Z$ is not empty.

However, it is consistent without Regularity that $A=\{\varnothing, A\}$ exists. In that case, $A=Z$ will satisfy your requirements and is certainly finite. This can be extended to produce "longer cycles" as well.

The key point in the standard definition is that it will ensure $Z$ must be infinite even if Regularity fails, as it allows us to prove there is a smallest such $Z$, which must not contain any $\in$-cycles.

Comment: In the way that I understand it, the more general form that you suggest is $\exists Z (Z\neq \varnothing \wedge \forall x(x\in Z \to \exists y (y\in Z \wedge x \in y)))$.

Comment: Yes. In ZF this will work just fine.